# Add 0 for cumulative sum based on condition in R

Tags: r, data.table, cumsum

I have an example data.table and I am trying to code 3 different cumulative sums by ID, one for each "Type". My data table is also sorted by date.

```
DT<-data.table(ID=c(A,A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C,C),date=c("2008-01-01","2009-01-01","2010-01-01","2011-01-01","1978-01-01","1982-01-01","1985-01-01","2001-01-01","2011-01-01","2015-01-01","2019-01-01"),Type=c(1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,1,3),Days=c(18,333,26,57,48,10,17,,212,55,64,18))
```

I tried:

```
DT[Type==1&order(date),cumdays1:=cumsum(Days),by=ID]
DT[Type==2&order(date),cumdays2:=cumsum(Days),by=ID]
DT[Type==3&order(date),cumdays3:=cumsum(Days),by=ID]
```

However, this gives me NA for when the Type is different to the one I was calculating.

```
    ID       date Type Days cumdays1 cumdays2 cumdays3
 1:  A 2008-01-01    1   18       18       NA       NA
 2:  A 2009-01-01    2  333       NA      333       NA
 3:  A 2010-01-01    2   26       NA      359       NA
 4:  A 2011-01-01    3   57       NA       NA       57
 5:  B 1978-01-01    3   48       NA       NA       48
 6:  B 1982-01-01    1   10       10       NA       NA
 7:  B 1985-01-01    1   17       27       NA       NA
 8:  C 2001-01-01    2  212       NA      212       NA
 9:  C 2011-01-01    2   55       NA      267       NA
10:  C 2015-01-01    1   64       64       NA       NA
11:  C 2019-01-01    3   18       NA       NA       18
```

I would like instead to continue calculate cumulative sum using Day=0 for these columns. I know I could code a separate Day variable for each Type, but is there a simpler code to do this at once?

My desired output

```
    ID       date Type Days cumdays1 cumdays2 cumdays3
 1:  A 2008-01-01    1   18       18       0        0
 2:  A 2009-01-01    2  333       18      333       0
 3:  A 2010-01-01    2   26       18      359       0
 4:  A 2011-01-01    3   57       18      359       57
 5:  B 1978-01-01    3   48       0        0        48
 6:  B 1982-01-01    1   10       10       0        48
 7:  B 1985-01-01    1   17       27       0        48
 8:  C 2001-01-01    2  212       0        212      0
 9:  C 2011-01-01    2   55       0        267      0
10:  C 2015-01-01    1   64       64       267      0
11:  C 2019-01-01    3   18       64       267      18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Base R:

```
transform(dt[order(dt$ID,dt$date),],
      cumdays = apply(Days * diag(max(Type))[Type,], 
                       2, \(x)ave(x,ID, FUN = cumsum)))

    ID       date Type Days cumdays.V1 cumdays.V2 cumdays.V3
 1:  A 2008-01-01    1   18         18          0          0
 2:  A 2009-01-01    2  333         18        333          0
 3:  A 2010-01-01    2   26         18        359          0
 4:  A 2011-01-01    3   57         18        359         57
 5:  B 1978-01-01    3   48          0          0         48
 6:  B 1982-01-01    1   10         10          0         48
 7:  B 1985-01-01    1   17         27          0         48
 8:  C 2001-01-01    2  212          0        212          0
 9:  C 2011-01-01    2   55          0        267          0
10:  C 2015-01-01    1   64         64        267          0
11:  C 2019-01-01    3   18         64        267         18
```

---

Tidyverse:

```
dt %>%
   arrange(ID, date) %>%
   mutate(name = Type) %>%
   pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, date, Type),
               names_prefix = 'cumdays',
               values_from = Days, values_fill = 0) %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with('cumdays'), cumsum), .by = ID)

# A tibble: 11 × 6
   ID    date        Type cumdays1 cumdays2 cumdays3
   <chr> <chr>      <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
 1 A     2008-01-01     1       18        0        0
 2 A     2009-01-01     2       18      333        0
 3 A     2010-01-01     2       18      359        0
 4 A     2011-01-01     3       18      359       57
 5 B     1978-01-01     3        0        0       48
 6 B     1982-01-01     1       10        0       48
 7 B     1985-01-01     1       27        0       48
 8 C     2001-01-01     2        0      212        0
 9 C     2011-01-01     2        0      267        0
10 C     2015-01-01     1       64      267        0
11 C     2019-01-01     3       64      267       18
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I still need to do order(date) to make the calculations correct?

Comment: @Hong I just noticed the output I have is not the desired output. Let me rectify that

Answer (score 1):

```
# you can calculate the cumsums in once, then dcast them
DT[, cumdays := cumsum(Days), by = .(ID, Type)]
DT <- dcast(DT, ID + date + Days ~ Type, value.var = "cumdays")

cols <- 4:6

DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, nafill, type = "locf"), ID, .SDcols = cols]

setnafill(DT, type = "const", fill = 0L, cols = cols)

setnames(DT, 4:6, paste0("cumdays", 1:3))

DT

#     ID       date Days cumdays1 cumdays2 cumdays3
# 1:   A 2008-01-01   18       18        0        0
# 2:   A 2009-01-01  333       18      333        0
# 3:   A 2010-01-01   26       18      359        0
# 4:   A 2011-01-01   57       18      359       57
# 5:   B 1978-01-01   48        0        0       48
# 6:   B 1982-01-01   10       10        0       48
# 7:   B 1985-01-01   17       27        0       48
# 8:   C 2001-01-01  212        0      212        0
# 9:   C 2011-01-01   55        0      267        0
# 10:  C 2015-01-01   64       64      267        0
# 11:  C 2019-01-01   18       64      267       18
```